# Put common label on columns in DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

How do I put labels on a DataFrame columns.

I have a list with names of the label columns I have to put.
This is the data frame

[image]

And I should make it look like this

[image]

I tried

```
columns = [
            ('Age', '0-18'),('Age', '19-25'),
            ('Education', 'Low'),('Education', 'Medium'),('Education', 'High')]

column_names = ['Age','Education']

labels = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns, columns)
df.columns = labels
```

But obviously it is not true and I can't seem to make it work. Any ideas will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Age', '0-18'),('Age', '19-25'),('Education', 'Low'),('Education', 'Medium'),('Education', 'High')])
data = [[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df
```

Out:

```
      Age         Education
   0-18 19-25   Low Medium  High
0   0     0      0    0       0
1   0     0      0    0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the pandas [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) often helps where the docs don't provide an immediate answer

With your variable:

```
column_tuples = [
        ('Age', '0-18'),('Age', '19-25'),
        ('Education', 'Low'),('Education', 'Medium'),('Education', 'High')]
```

These lines from the example snippets should help (I've edited them for your context)

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(column_tuples)

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 6), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns=index)

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
              Age                Education...       
            0-18     19-25       Low    Medium      High
A       0.895717  0.805244 -1.206412   1.340309 -1.170299 
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003  -1.187678  1.130127
C      -1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  -2.211372  0.974466

[3 rows x 6 columns]
```

If you do want to label the two levels of column labels, you can set `names=['Level 0 Name', 'Level 1 Name']` when you create the index (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples) for `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples()`)

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(column_tuples, names=['Level 0 Name', 'Level 1 Name'])
```